# How do I authenticate a proxy in playwright

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, playwright

I have this arg in my playwright browser options, `'--proxy-server=endpoint:port'` and I could authenticate my proxy in puppeteer with `await page.authenticate({username, password});`. I could not find any ways to do the same operation with playwright. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can load pages over a HTTP proxy in **two** ways:

1/ set it globally for the entire browser:

```js
const browser = await chromium.launch({
    proxy: {
        server: 'http://myproxy.com:3128',
        user: 'usr',
        password: 'pwd'
    }
});
```

2/ or you can set it per context:

```js
const browser = await chromium.launch({
    proxy: { server: 'per-context' }
});
const context = await browser.newContext({
    proxy: {
        server: 'http://myproxy.com:3128',
        user: 'usr',
        password: 'pwd'
    }
})
```

It's all documented in Playwright documentation [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/network?_highlight=proxy#http-proxy).